# trying to increment a value of the object by assigning to a variable i . Please advice

Tags: ruby, capybara, rubyxl

Below is my code.I'm trying to input value from the excel sheet to the text boxes in the page. Eg : In text box id is 'allocationRegContrib[17].newFundValue' I want to input a value say 20. Similarly for another text box whose id is 'allocationRegContrib[18].newFundValue', I want to input a value say 40. How to achieve. Similarly the id goes on upto 60. But I do not want to input in all the textboxes. So I'm trying to use like fill_in "allocationRegContrib[i].newFundValue".

```
     @i=17
    for j in (workbook.first_row..workbook.last_row)

     for k in (workbook.first_column..workbook.last_column)

      if(k==1)
    fill_in "searchInput", :with => workbook.cell(j,1)
    find(:xpath, '//*[@id="sdcaLink"]').click
    sleep 3


    else
    choose("sdcaOption", :option => "YES")
    select(workbook.cell(j,k), :from => 'sdcaDuration')
    fill_in "allocationRegContrib[i].newFundValue", :with => workbook.cell(j,k)
    @i=i+1
    find(:xpath, '//*[@id="specialDCAupdate"]').click
```

But it does not work for me. Error is "unable to locate the capybara element allocationRegContrib[i].newFundValue". Please Advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have two issues:

`i` and `@i` aren't the same thing. I think you may want to use `i` in all the places. `i` is a local variable (that is, a simple plain old variable). `@i` is an instance variable of a class, like a "field" or "property" in other languages.

```
fill_in "allocationRegContrib[i].newFundValue", :with => workbook.cell(j,k)
```

should probably be:

```
fill_in "allocationRegContrib[#{i}].newFundValue", :with => workbook.cell(j,k)
```

`#{i}` puts in the value of the variable `i` into the string, then the capybara matcher can find, for example, element `allocationRegContrib[17].newFundValue` (when i=17)

Comment: @ Satya Thank you. It worked fine. In order to increment the value of 'i', can we just use i=i+1?

Comment: Yes `i = i + 1` works, as does `i += 1`. Unlike some languages, `i++` does not work.